# I am getting error while downloading spacenet3 road extraction dataset using aws console and have an aws active account

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was trying running this code in aws console

```
aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset/spacenet/SN3_roads/tarballs/SN3_roads_train_AOI_4_Shanghai.tar.gz .
```

and this is the error I m getting this error

```
Unknown options: cp,s3://spacenet-dataset/spacenet/SN3_roads/tarballs/SN3_roads_train_AOI_4_Shanghai.tar.gz,s3://spacefiles/aws,s3,cp,s3://spacenet-dataset/spacenet/SN3_roads/tarballs/SN3_roads_train_AOI_4_Shanghai.tar.gz
```

Comment: The command is correct. You have to update question with more details of what exactly are you doing. How do you run the command in "aws console"? Why did you tag the question "windows"? Are you using console in windows operating system?